# The mysql driver is not currently installed, but pdo_mysql.so/mysqli.so is loaded

Tags: php, mysql

I installed PHP 7 in a docker container as fcgi. My php.ini looks like this:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/curl.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/igbinary.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/intl.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/json.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/mcrypt.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/memcached.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/opcache.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlite.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/readline.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/sqlite3.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xsl.so
```

If I run `php -m` I get the following output:

```
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
gd
hash
iconv
igbinary
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

You see mysqli and pdo_mysql are definitely loaded. But if I run my php application it says: `The mysql driver is not currently installed`.
I can connect to mysql on command line successfully. What is wrong here?

Comment: Well, are you using mysql to make your query or mysqli?

Comment: Is your application based on the Zend Framework?

Comment: It is Magento 2 which is based on the Zend Framework and as far as I see it uses PDO.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql` extenstion was deprecated and is totally removed in php7 so do not be surprised. Just quickly change to mysqli or pdo

Comment: As you can see mysql is not even loaded :-)

Comment: You don't understand the question. It is not asking why mysql extension is not loaded, It is asking why **PDO mysql** driver is not loaeded.

Comment: But `php -m` says that `pdo_mysql` is loaded? Or do I misunderstand something? :-)

Comment: Can you show us a configuration of your db adapter?

Comment: How can I do this?